# How to boost up a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing

I am suffering from slow for-loop execution in R. Here I provide a part of my code which is producing delay.

```r
## subsitutes for original data
DC <- matrix(rnorm(10), ncol=101, nrow=6400)
C <- matrix(rnorm(20), ncol=101, nrow=6400)


N <- 80
Vcut <- ncol(DC) 
V <- seq(-2.9,2.5,length=Vcut)
fNC <- matrix(NA, nrow=(N*N), ncol=Vcut)
fNDC <- matrix(NA, nrow=(N*N), ncol=Vcut)


Arbfunc <- function(dV){

b <- matrix(NA, nrow=1, ncol=Vcut)

  for(i in 1:(N*N)) {
    for (n in 1:Vcut) {
      for (k in 1:Vcut) {
        b[k] = (V[2]-V[1])*(exp((-1)*abs(V[k])))*exp(abs(V[n]-V[k])/dV)*(C[i,k]/V[k])
      }
      fNC[i,n] = exp(1*abs(V[n]))*(1/(2*dV))*(sum(b[]))
      fNDC[i,n] = DC[i,n]/fNC[i,n]
    }
  }   
}

Arbfunc(0.5)
```

Since I need to compare the results among the various values of **dV's**, this code should run at least within few seconds. But the result is

```
user   system  elapsed
40.15   0.03   40.24
```

which is too much slow for enough comparison. I tried several parallelization methods, but the result was not satisfactory (40 -> 25 secs although I used 11 threads in my pc).

Therefore, my guess is that the bottleneck is this for-loop itself, not a non-parallel code. Could you give me some advice to improve this for-loop or hint for parallelization ? Just a short comment would be grateful.

Comment: Have you considered using `apply`/`sapply`/`tapply` ?

Comment: what's the mathematical formulation you are trying to achieve?  If you could rewrite it using the functions `abs`, `exp`, etc. on matrices/rows/columns instead of on individual elements (ie. vectorize it in R terms) you would get significant speedup.  Since you are already preallocating the matrices I doubt using the `*apply` functions would help much. If you could rewrite it using matrix multiplication or the like, it'll probably run in parallel anyway using underlying fortran libraries. Simple constants like `(V[1]-V[2])` could obviously be pulled outside the loops.

Comment: Thank you so much for comments, let me try with apply function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Big thanks to @Mikko Marttila for correcting functions 3 and 4 and providing the idea for function 5.**

R is best approached with vectorized options instead of explicit loops. For instance, the inner loop with `k`:

```
for (k in 1:Vcut) {
  b[k] = (V[2]-V[1])*(exp((-1)*abs(V[k])))*exp(abs(V[n]-V[k])/dV)*(C[i,k]/V[k])
}
```

That's the same as saying

```
(V[2]-V[1])*(exp((-1)*abs(V)))*exp(abs(V[n]-V)/dV)*(C[i,]/V)
```

This small change gives us a 500x performance boost for this part of the function:

```
Unit: microseconds
         expr     min      lq      mean  median      uq     max neval
       k_loop 13186.7 13603.2 14605.471 13832.9 14517.8 41935.1   100
 k_vectorized    16.4    17.6    25.559    28.8    32.0    52.7   100
```

Now if we look at the outer loop with the i, we see that there's really no need to loop by each row. We could instead make a matrix for the the `sum(b[k])` statement turning this:

```
(V[2]-V[1])*(exp((-1)*abs(V)))*exp(abs(V[n]-V)/dV)*(C[i,]/V)
```

Into this:

```
(V[2]-V[1])*(exp((-1)*abs(V)))*exp(abs(V[n]-V)/dV)*(t(C)/V)
```

That just saved us `N*N*k` loops. In your case, that's  646,400 loops.

To put it altogether, we would have:

```
Arbfunc3 <- function(dV){
    for (n in 1:Vcut) {
      sum_b = colSums((V[2]-V[1])*(exp((-1)*abs(V)))*exp(abs(V[n]-V)/dV)*(t(C)/V))
      fNC[, n] = exp(1*abs(V[n]))*(1/(2*dV))*(sum_b)
      fNDC[, n] = DC[,n]/fNC[,n]
    }
}
```

My median time for microbenchmark is 750 milliseconds for this alternative.

To further improve performance, we need to address the `V[n] - V`. Thankfully, the `R` has a function - `outer(V, V, '-')` and this will produce a matrix with all combinations we need.

```
Arbfunc4 <- function(dV) {
  sum_b = apply((V[2]-V[1])*(exp((-1)*abs(V)))*exp(abs(outer(V, V, '-')) / dV) / V, 2, function(x) colSums(x * t(C)))

  fNC = exp(1*abs(V))*(1/(2*dV))*t(sum_b)
  fNDC= DC/t(fNC)
  fNDC
}
```

Thanks to @Mikko Marttila for a suggestion to get rid of apply with a dot product.

```
Arbfunc5 <- function(dV) {
  a = (V[2] - V[1]) * exp(-abs(V)) * t(C) / V
  b = exp(abs(outer(V, V, "-")) / dV) %*% a

  fNC = exp(1*abs(V))*(1/(2*dV))*(b)
  fNDC= DC/t(fNC)
  fNDC
}
```

Here is the system.time for each solution (Arbfunc2 is the elimination of the k_loop). The optimized solution is **2,600** times faster than the original.

```
> system.time(Arbfunc(0.5))
   user  system elapsed 
  78.03    0.39   79.72 
> system.time(Arbfunc2(0.5))
   user  system elapsed 
  10.41    0.03   10.46 
> system.time(Arbfunc3(0.5))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.69    0.13    0.81 
> system.time(Arbfunc4(0.5))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.43    0.05    0.47 
> system.time(Arbfunc5(0.5))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.03    0.00    0.03
```

**Final Edit:** Here's the complete code that I ran after restarting R and emptying my environment. No errors:

```
## subsitutes for original data
DC <- matrix(rnorm(10), ncol=101, nrow=6400)
C <- matrix(rnorm(20), ncol=101, nrow=6400)

N <- 80
Vcut <- ncol(DC) 
V <- seq(-2.9,2.5,length=Vcut)

# Unneeded for Arbfunc4 adn Arbfunc5
# Corrected from NA to NA_real_ to prevent coercion from logical to numeric
# h/t to @HenrikB
fNC <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow=(N*N), ncol=Vcut)
fNDC <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow=(N*N), ncol=Vcut)

Arbfunc <- function(dV){
  b <- matrix(NA, nrow=1, ncol=Vcut)

  for(i in 1:(N*N)) {
    for (n in 1:Vcut) {
      for (k in 1:Vcut) {
        b[k] = (V[2]-V[1])*(exp((-1)*abs(V[k])))*exp(abs(V[n]-V[k])/dV)*(C[i,k]/V[k])
      }
      fNC[i,n] = exp(1*abs(V[n]))*(1/(2*dV))*(sum(b[]))
      fNDC[i,n] = DC[i,n]/fNC[i,n]
    }
  }
  fNDC
}

Arbfunc2 <- function(dV){
  b <- matrix(NA, nrow=1, ncol=Vcut)

  for(i in 1:(N*N)) {
    for (n in 1:Vcut) {
      sum_b = sum((V[2]-V[1])*(exp((-1)*abs(V)))*exp(abs(V[n]-V)/dV)*(C[i,]/V))
      fNC[i,n] = exp(1*abs(V[n]))*(1/(2*dV))*(sum_b)
      fNDC[i,n] = DC[i,n]/fNC[i,n]
    }
  }
  fNDC
}

Arbfunc3 <- function(dV){
  for (n in 1:Vcut) {
    sum_b = colSums((V[2]-V[1])*(exp((-1)*abs(V)))*exp(abs(V[n]-V)/dV)*(t(C)/V))
    fNC[, n] = exp(1*abs(V[n]))*(1/(2*dV))*(sum_b)
    fNDC[, n] = DC[,n]/fNC[,n]
  }
  fNDC
}

Arbfunc4 <- function(dV) {
  sum_b = apply((V[2]-V[1])*(exp((-1)*abs(V)))*exp(abs(outer(V, V, '-')) / dV) / V, 2, function(x) colSums(x * t(C)))

  fNC = exp(1*abs(V))*(1/(2*dV))*t(sum_b)
  DC/t(fNC)
}

Arbfunc5 <- function(dV) {
#h/t to Mikko Marttila for dot product
  a = (V[2] - V[1]) * exp(-abs(V)) * t(C) / V
  b = exp(abs(outer(V, V, "-")) / dV) %*% a

  fNC = exp(1*abs(V))*(1/(2*dV))*(b)
  DC/t(fNC)
}

#system.time(res <- Arbfunc(0.5))
system.time(res2 <- Arbfunc2(0.5))
system.time(res3 <- Arbfunc3(0.5))
system.time(res4 <- Arbfunc4(0.5))
system.time(res5 <- Arbfunc5(0.5))

all.equal(res2,res3,res4,res5)
```

As @HenrikB mentions, the `fNC` and `fNDC` initialize as logical matrices. That means we get a performance hit when coercing them to `real` matrices. Doing it the incorrect is a one-time hit of 1 ms for this dataset but if this coercion were in a loop, it could really add up.

```
mat_NA_real_ <- function() {
  mat = matrix(NA_real_, nrow = 6400, ncol = 101)
  mat[1,1] = 1
}

mat_NA <- function() {
  mat = matrix(NA, nrow = 6400, ncol = 101)
  mat[1,1] = 1
}
microbenchmark(mat_NA_real_(), mat_NA())

Unit: microseconds
           expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq     max neval
 mat_NA_real_()  979.5  992.25 1490.081  998.65 1021.1  7612.5   100
       mat_NA() 1865.8 1883.30 3793.119 1911.30 5335.4 53635.2   100
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was about to post, great answer! Thinking in vectors makes for simpler and much faster code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I look into details in your code. I found an error when I tried to run Arbfunc3, with an error message "Error in C/V : non-conformable arrays".
How can I deal with that? I tried to make C as data.frame but as a result it does not improve speed much.

Comment: I pasted the complete code at the end - it works for me without errors. I just tried ```C/V``` and it ran. I recommend setting a seed at the top ```set.seed(0)``` and cleaning out your global environment with ```rm(list=ls())```.

Comment: Nice answer. I think you need to transpose the `C` matrix in `Argfunc3()` though, and then take `colSums()` rather than `rowSums()`. This is because the original loop divides each row in `C` with `V`, but without transposing, `C / V` will recycle `V` and divide columns of  `C` instead. In this case the result happens to be the same bacause `C` is constructed by repeating 20 values, which makes the sums equal, but this won't hold in the general case.

Comment: You can then also write the `apply()` as a matrix product instead, with `a = (V[2] - V[1]) * exp(-abs(V)) * t(C) / V` and `b = exp(abs(outer(V, V, "-")) / dV) %*% a`.

Comment: @Mikko Martilla I fixed ArbFunc3 - my attempts to salvage 4 are not ending up as ```identical()``` although the numbers seem pretty similar. Any ideas if the fix is correct?

Comment: I think that it's a floating point thing - the ```abs(Arbfunc4(0.5) - Arbfunc2(0.5))``` is at least less than 0.00005 within each other. I'll update the benchmarks later tonight but @Mikko Martilla's matrix product speeds it up to around 50 ms. It's amazing that that's only 4 times slower than the original ```k_loop``` which was just one very small part.

Comment: Thank you so much !! In fact currently I cannot understand from Arbfunc 3 :(. I'll try to grasp all of these modifications to my original code. Again thank you for providing me a chance to study how to deal with stupid for-loops !

Comment: Yeah it's probably fp error. For calculations like this you're usually better off comparing with `all.equal()` rather than `identical()`.

Comment: With ```all.equal()```, the solutions are all the same. Answer is edited to be better flowing.

Comment: MEMORY => SPEED: Right now you're allocating logical matrices when you use `matrix(NA, ...)`.  Make sure to allocate numeric matrices, i.e. `matrix(NA_real_, ...)`.  See https://www.jottr.org/2014/06/17/matrixna-wrong-way/ for an explanation.